# MongoDB: N-N relationship table Query using Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, relationship

I have a relationship table (containing only 2 fields) for N-N relationship mapping purpose:

**Example:** ProductRelation Collection (in MongoDB) with below 3 documents:

```
{ p1: '0001', p2: '0002' },
{ p1: '0003', p2: '0001' },
{ p1: '0004', p2: '0005' }
```

**Question:**
If I search using '0001' product, I wish to find all its related products, expected return:

```
{ '0002', '0003' }
```

Is there any way to do this? I try using 'aggregate' but not successful. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. This is what I did, something like below:

```
ProductRelation.aggregate (
  [
    { $match: { $or: [ { p1: '0001' }, { product2: '0001' }] } },
    { $project: { p1: { $cond: { 
                           if: { $eq: [ '0001', "$p1" ]  },
                           then: "$$REMOVE",
                           else: "$p1"
                       } },
                  p2: { $cond: { 
                           if: { $eq: [ '0001', "$p2" ]  },
                           then: "$$REMOVE",
                           else: "$p2"
                       } },
                }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { myList: { $mergeObjects : [ "$p1",  "$p2" ] } } } },
    { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: [ "$myList"] } }
  ]
```

**Note:** Just need to replace '0001' with pass-in parameter.